# Perl cgi скрипт и определение ip

Tags: perl, cgi

Итак всем доброго времени суток.

Меня зовут Азамат и вот мой вопрос. Как определить ip адрес в cgi скриптах. к примеру, если нужно подключится к удаленному компьютеру. А там сидит человек, который не знает как ее определять. И чтобы он заходил на мою страничку и у меня сохранялось его ip. Ну примерно так.

Можете написать код cgi скрипта или как его определить перенаправлением на другой сайт и чтобы она записалась у меня на страничке (тоже код)??

Спасибо большое за внимание! Извиняюсь, если где-то неправильно изъяснился. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}
```

выведет адрес посетителя

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl


use CGI qw(:standard);
@ee=(
  "CHARSET",
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT",
  "HTTP_REFERER",
  "REMOTE_ADDR",
  "REMOTE_HOST"
);


$comment="ЗДравствуйте!!";

open ( ADD_IP , ">file.txt" );
foreach $e(@ee)
{
  print ADD_IP "<b>$e</b>: $ENV{$e}<br>\n\n\n";
};

  close ( ADD_IP ); 



print "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\n";
foreach $e(@ee)
{
  print "<b>$e</b>: $ENV{$e}<br>\n\n\n";
};


вот код программы
можете подсказать что не так?он выводит один и тот же адрес для всех
http://users.nsunc.com/~atazhibay/cgi-bin/ip.cgi

Answer (score 0):

вот скрипт, попробуй запустить и разобраться

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# переменные окружения
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
while (($key, $val) = each %ENV) {
    print "$key = $val<BR>\n";
}
```